# FX conversion depending on FX exchange (cross df multiplication)

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using the following data, which looks like the following: (financial data from quantmod)

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  symbol     year adjusted Total.Revenue
  <chr>     <int>    <dbl>         <dbl>
1 MSFT       2017   101.         9.66e10
2 5563.T     2017   307.         7.13e10
3 WB         2017    91.0        1.15e 9
4 0992.HK    2017     3.94       4.30e10
5 005930.KS  2017 45600.         2.40e14
```

And

```
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  date       jpy_usd hkd_usd  krw_usd
  <date>       <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
1 2018-07-09 0.00904   0.127 0.000900
```

What I am trying to do is to `separate` the `symbol` column in `df1` so that everything after the `.` would be put into a new column. So `T`, `HK` and `KS` would be under a new column and if there is no characters after the `.` then leave a blank space or `USD`. I have tried the following with not much luck.

```
dftest <- df1 %>%
  separate(symbol, into = c("ticker", "country"),
           sep = "(?<=[A-Z])\\.(?=[a-z]+)", convert = TRUE)
```

Then I am trying to multiply the `df2` data so that. `jpy_usd` corresponds to `T`, `hkd_usd` corresponds to `HK` and `krw_usd` corresponds to `KS`. Then multiply the `adjusted` and `Total Revenue` by the corresponding exchange rates. The columns created from `separate` which would be left blank should have no exchange conversion since they are already in USD.

So finally some of the values should look like:

`5563.T - adjusted = 307*0.00904 = 2.77`
`0992.HK - Total.Revenue = 5461000000` etc.

I hope I am clear in what I am trying to do. If possible I am trying to do it in the `dplyr` package.

Data 1:

```
df1 <- structure(list(symbol = c("MSFT", "5563.T", "WB", "0992.HK", 
"005930.KS"), year = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L), adjusted = c(101.459557, 
307, 90.970001, 3.945, 45600), Total.Revenue = c(9.6571e+10, 
7.1346e+10, 1150054000, 43034731000, 2.3958e+14)), .Names = c("symbol", 
"year", "adjusted", "Total.Revenue"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Data 2:

```
df2 <- structure(list(date = structure(17721, class = "Date"), jpy_usd = 0.00904, 
    hkd_usd = 0.127416, krw_usd = 9e-04), row.names = c(NA, -1L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("date", 
"jpy_usd", "hkd_usd", "krw_usd"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer for part 1,**

```
dftest <- df1 %>% 
  separate(symbol, into = c("ticker", "country"), 
  sep = "[.]", convert = TRUE)
```

Results in

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  ticker country  year adjusted Total.Revenue
  <chr>  <chr>   <int>    <dbl>         <dbl>
1 MSFT   NA       2017   101.         9.66e10
2 5563   T        2017   307          7.13e10
3 WB     NA       2017    91.0        1.15e 9
4 0992   HK       2017     3.94       4.30e10
5 005930 KS       2017 45600          2.40e14
```

**Answer for part 2**

It's abit ugly... But does the job

```
dffinal <- dftest %>% 
  mutate(exchange.rates = ifelse(country == "T", df2$jpy_usd, 
ifelse(country == "HK", df2$hkd_usd, ifelse(country == "KS", 
df2$krw_usd, 0)))) %>% 
  mutate(exchange.rates = ifelse(is.na(country), 1, exchange.rates))%>% 
  mutate(adjusted = adjusted * exchange.rates) %>% 
  mutate(Total.Revenue = Total.Revenue * exchange.rates)
```

Results in

```
    # A tibble: 5 x 6
  ticker country  year adjusted Total.Revenue exchange.rates
  <chr>  <chr>   <int>    <dbl>         <dbl>          <dbl>
1 MSFT   NA       2017  101.     96571000000         1      
2 5563   T        2017    2.78     644967840         0.00904
3 WB     NA       2017   91.0     1150054000         1      
4 0992   HK       2017    0.503   5483313285.        0.127  
5 005930 KS       2017   41.0   215622000000         0.0009
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is great and I have managed to get it working almost working on the full data set. I just have one more obstacle. I am at the part `  mutate(exchange.rates = ifelse(is.na(country), 1, exchange.rates))%>% 
  mutate(adjusted = adjusted * exchange.rates) %>% 
  mutate(Total.Revenue = Total.Revenue * exchange.rates)` However in the full data set I have 83 columns I want to make the `FX` conversion. I am trying to `mutate()` columns [5:83] for example instead of writing out the column names for all columns. Any advice here?

Comment: This seems to do the trick : `mutate_at(.funs = funs(fx = .*exchange.rates), .vars = vars(Cash.And.Cash.Equivalents:Change.In.Cash.and.Cash.Equivalents))`

Thanks again